# Why during autoboxing final long to Byte compilation error happens, but final int to Byte is ok?

Tags: java, autoboxing

There is no error during auto-boxing of constants with `int` and `short` types to `Byte`, but constant with `long` type do has error. Why?

```
final int i = 3;
Byte b = i; // no error

final short s = 3;
Byte b = s; // no error


final long l = 3;
Byte b = l; // error
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [JLS Sec 5.2, "Assignment contexts"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) (emphasis mine):

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type **byte, short, char, or int**:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.
> - A narrowing primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion may be used if the type of the variable is:
>
>   - Byte and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type byte.
>   - ...

It's simply not allowed for `long`s by the spec.

Note that the second bullet point here says that this happens irrespective of the boxing: assigning a constant `long` expression to a `byte` variable would similarly fail:

```
// Both compiler errors.
byte primitive = 0L;
Byte wrapped = 0L;
```

Comment: I am curious to learn why. Could it be related to the fact that long is to machine words?

Comment: Probably mostly because `int` is the default type for constant values, including expressions, so there will be a _lot_ of code like `short s = 123` and if such a narrowing conversion weren't used, you'd need casts everywhere. In particular, Java has no syntax for literals of narrower the types. On the other hand, if the type of the expression is explicitly `long`, because `L` has been used on a constant or some part is constant, then it may be an error to narrow it, and this situation is much less common than the `int` case and I guess the balance falls in favor making it an error.

Comment: Note also that the autoboxing really doesn't have much to do with this: the same thing applies to purely primitive types. The rules were just extended to include assignment to boxed types when they were added. @JonathanRosenne

Comment: @BeeOnRope " the autoboxing really doesn't have much to do with this" Indeed: I had a comment along those lines in [an earlier version of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46206395/1). However, I removed it, because the section I quote does actually explicitly describe narrowing followed by boxing; so I removed my mention of this point and included the extra quote instead.

Comment: I think the error makes sense because a `byte` can only hold values between -128..127, and a narrowing cast from a `long` (which is used for storing much larger values) would usually be a programming error.

Comment: @MickMnemonic the same argument doesn't apply to an `int`, though: that can represent values outside that range. The compiler only allows it for `int` if the constant value is in a range representable by `byte`. There's no (obvious) reason why you couldn't do the same with `long`.

Comment: There may be a parallel with the JVM type system, which doesn't distinguish between `int` and smaller types in [the constant pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4), "local variables" (registers) and the stack machine stack.  But if that's the actual reason I'd say the language designers were led astray by a leaky abstraction.